# Geb+Spock+Groovy - taking data from a db and using as values for input statements in Automations

Tags: sql, groovy, junit, spock, geb

I am trying to figure out how to use the exsiting data I have and either storing it in a array to be used as data values for my automation or using the data directly from the db.

Breakdown

1. Existing db with populated data
2. LoginPage to be automated
3. Harded user login and user password
4. Existing db has username and password data for the LoginPage ( test environment)
5. Script created for connect and capturing the needed values
6. Whats next? How to use that captured username and password from the db to be used within my code so I wont have to hard-code the username and password fields.

NOTE: I would of shared the code it is company specific. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

We store the user data in an enum, we then use the enum data to insert / delete the user data into / from our DB.

This gets a little wordy but here is a rough idea of the structure we use and then how we use it.  I have genericised it a lot so hopefully it's still semi-workable.

In the sample below our **GenericUserNavigationBlah** class is just a handy class we use to wrap up a lot of user navigation patterns, including logging in.

The **ExternalUser** class is where all our user data gets stored.  I've left out most of the fields we use to represent a user but ideally it would match what a user looks like in your own DB.

You probably didn't need a sample of the **Database** class, it was only included as a tie-in to what was happening in the **ExternalUser** class.

Finally **SampleSpec** give you a rough idea of how we use these things together, because I've watered down the ExternalUser class it won't work unless you implement the missing bits.

Hope this helps,
Deon.

---

```
import geb.Browser
import ...ExternalUser

class GenericUserNavigationBlah {

    Browser browser

    GenericUserNavigationBlah(Browser browser){
        this.browser = browser
    }

    void setBrowser(Browser browser) {
        this.browser = browser
    }

    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        browser."$name"(*args)
    }

    def propertyMissing(String name) {
        browser."$name"
    }

    def logon(ExternalUser credentials) {
        assert browser.isAt(LogonPage)
        browser.userID = credentials.userId
        browser.password = credentials.pass
        browser.logonButton.click()     
    }

    // + tons more useful helper methods of generic user navigation blahness :)
}
```

---

```
import ...Database

enum ExternalUser {

    TESTUSER1(1, "FirstName","LastName","99TEST_USER","Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious", "ImagineAnEncryptedPasswordGoesHere")

    private ExternalUser(int uniqueId, String firstName, String lastName, String userId, String pass, String encryptedPass) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId
        this.firstName = firstName
        this.lastName = lastName
        this.userId = userId
        this.pass = pass
        this.encryptedPass = encryptedPass
    }

    // fields should match your database table
    private final int uniqueId
    private final String firstName
    private final String lastName
    private final String userId
    private final String pass
    private final String encryptedPass

    def create() {
        remove()
        Database.instance.ourDatabase.execute("insert into YourUserTable (UniqueId, FirstName, LastName, UserID, Password, EncryptedPassword) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [uniqueId, firstName, lastName, userId, pass, encryptedPass])
    }

    def remove() {
        Database.instance.ourDatabase.execute("delete from YourUserTable where UniqueId = ?", uniqueId)
    }
}
```

---

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

@Singleton(strict=false)
class Database {

    private Database() {
        super()

        addShutdownHook {
            closeConnections()  
        }
    }

    private static final String JTDS_DRIVER = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"

    private Sql ourDatabaseSql = null

    private Sql getSql(String url, String user, String pw) {
        Sql.newInstance(url, user, pw, JTDS_DRIVER)
    }


    def Sql getOurDatabaseSql() {
        if (null == ourDatabaseSql) {
            ourDatabaseSql = getSql("DBURL", "DBUSER", "DBPASS") // We user a config slurper but I didn't want to go into that here
        }

        ourDatabaseSql
    }

    /**
     * Cleanup any connections that have been created
     * @return
     */
    private closeConnections() {
        closeQuietly(ourDatabaseSql)
    }

    /**
     * Close the given connection if not null, swallowing any exceptions
     * @param sql
     * @return
     */
    private closeQuietly(Sql sql) {
        if (null != sql) {
            try {
                sql.close()
            } catch (Exception e) {
                println "Exception closing sql: " + e
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
import ...ExternalUser
import ...GenericUserNavigationBlah
...

class SampleSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    GenericUserNavigationBlah gunb = new GenericUserNavigationBlah(browser)
    @Shared ExternalUser user = ExternalUser.TESTUSER1

    def setup() {
        user.create()
    }

    def "Main page is displayed when a user logs in successfully"() {
        when: "A user logs in successfully"
            gunb.logon( user)

        then: "the main page is displayed"
            at MainPage
    }

    def "User is locked out after 3 failed login attempts"() {
        given: "a user has attempted 2 bad logins already"
            user.setBadLoginAttempts(2)

        and: "the user is on the login page"
            at LogonPage

        and: "they are not locked out"
            !user.isLockedOut()

        when: "they attempt a third bad login"  
            userNameInput = user.userId
            passwordInput = "IWonderIfMyCapsLockIsOn..."

        then: "they are now locked out"
            user.isLockedOut()

        and: "the generic Invalid credentials message is displayed on the logon page"
            at LogonPage
            someMessage.text() == "Invalid credentials used, try again."
    }

    def "User is logged in successfully on 3rd attempt after 2 bad attempts"() {
        given: "a user has attempted 2 bad logins already"
            user.setBadLoginAttempts(2)

        and: "the user is on the login page"
            at LogonPage

        and: "they are not locked out"
            !user.isLockedOut()

        when: "they attempt a third good login" 
            userNameInput = user.userId
            passwordInput = user.pass

        then: "the main page is displayed"
            at MainPage
    }
}
```

Comment: this is extactly what I was looking for , thank you and I appeciate all your help on this, my rep is under 15 but I still clicked ur answer. Once again thanks.